# OpenLayers. Creating dynamic marker not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have this code:

```
   var markers = JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
   for (var i in markers)
   {
     var id = markers[i].id;
     var lon = markers[i].lon;
     var lat = markers[i].lat;


     icon1 = new OpenLayers.Icon('../imag/pine.png', size, offset);
     window[id] = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'), icon1);
     window[id].id = id;
   }
```

It works perfectly in chrome, and allows me to access the marker globally using window[id].
The problem is that in firefox im getting this error: TypeError: window[id] is undefined.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The problem was that id was a number. It seems like window[number] doesnt work in firefox. That might be a bug or something. I dont know. I added a blank space to the id and all right.